# python selenium locating elements issue

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I was making a bot with selenium but I can not click here:
[image]

There are many classes and I can not find which one I should use , because I tried something but didn't do it.

For example, button name is **OTURUM AÇ** and I wrote like this , but it does not work.

```
browser = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="OTURUM AÇ"]').click()
```

Update from comments: https://dlive.tv/ I wanna log in there. But I can't.

Comment: Try copying and entering its XPath

Comment: Change elements to the element

Comment: I copied XPath way but still It does not work :(

Comment: @whisber Welcome to the SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. the image of html code is bad practice no one will write that for you from the image. add it as part of post itself in stead of image. Adding external link is also a bad practice since they keep changing and expire.

Comment: Can you share the page URL?

Comment: https://dlive.tv/ I wanna log in there. But I can't.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='OTURUM AÇ']")))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', btn)
```

Comment: Due to ElementNotInteractable exception, I used 'execute_script'

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are trying to find a button which has a text 'OTURUM AÇ' inside of it. In html which you add to question, there is no `<button>` tag so you need to search this element with `<span>`.

```
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="OTURUM AÇ"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', login)
```

In html, it is not mandatory to use a `<button>` tag to place a button on page so make sure you check the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong locator. There is login button with `span` tag, not `button`.
Locotor will be:

```
//span[text()="OTURUM AÇ"]
```

But using text in locators is not good practice. You can rewrite it using css:

```
.sign-register-buttons .btnA span
```

or the same xpath locator:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'sign-register-buttons')]//*[contains(@class, 'btnA')]//span
```

They will work for any site language.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **OTURUM AÇ** you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sign-register-buttons flex-align-center']//span[text()='OTURUM AÇ']").click()
```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sign-register-buttons flex-align-center']//span[text()='OTURUM AÇ']"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```